# Submit a form based on the javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

What I want is to be able to submit a form when ever a user presses some key like tab or enter (i.e. that will case him to lose focus) also clicking outside of the text field should trigger a submit. However when ever he click on the cancel button it should prevent the submit ion

html structure look like this

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="text" onblur="$(this).closest('form').submit();">
  <a id"submit">submit</a>
  <a id"cancel">cancel</a>
</form>
```

Currently what happens is that when a user presses enter a form is submitted twice and it should be submitted only once. When he presses a cancel a form is submitted and cancelled right after that.

Does anyone have any idea how can I write some javascript code that can accomplish this behaviour (the idea for is take form the jira in-line edit mode and I am trying to construct something in similar manner)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to provide you with another you could approach this by using jQuery and it's `.change()` [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/). This way when the user clicks off of the input element, it'll trigger the .change() event and you can submit a form within it's callback function. If the user cancels then you can handle that event normally, same with the submit button click.

The Form:

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="text">
  <a id="cancel">cancel</a>
  <a id="submit">submit</a>
</form>
```

The Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //submit the form
        console.log('form submitted by button click')
    });
    $('#cancel').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //close form?
        console.log('cancelled form');
    });

    $('#text').change(function(){
        //submit the form
        console.log('form submitted, maybe hide form now?');
    });
});
```

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgnl/t2PSc/1/).

Comment: sorry I saw that you needed links, updated my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Keep submit flag to prevent duplication on form submit. Something like [that](http://jsbin.com/gedazowu/1/)

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="text" onblur="submitForm('form');">
  <button onclick="submitForm('form');">submit</button>
  <button type="cancel">cancel</button>
</form>
<script>
  var submitFlag = {};

  function submitForm(id){
    if(!submitFlag[id]){
      submitFlag[id] = true;
      $('#' + id).submit();
    } else {
      // do nothing
      // alert('Form already submitted');
      return;
    } 
  }

</script>
```

Comment: I have to use links for the submit/cancel events. as they are triggering ajax refreshes on the page based on the selection (i.e. even if a user selects cancel there are stuff that should happen so all I have to do is prevent a form submittion that is already in progress)

Comment: Ow, maybe than crate fuction, which will submit form in setInterval. You can save timer descriptor to stop submitting and continue process it as you want?